# Why does my mac play audio in a laggy and noisy way?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, video

My Macbook pro (M1 max) suddenly plays music in slow motion with so much lag and noise. Also happens to videos playing. Same when I am having video meetings. What could be the problem?
This also happens for system sounds.

https://youtu.be/_azHCqfW26g

Comment: This is a very general question. Please show logs